# Getting slightly different results in fitting a logit model in R and Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I'm fitting some data to a Logit model in both *Mathematica* and `R` and I'm getting slightly different results.

`R` code:

```
data = read.table("http://www.rni.helsinki.fi/~kja/epid12/BCG.dat",header=T)
logitmodel = glm(cbind(D,H)~BCG,data=data,family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(logitmodel)
```

*Mathematica* code:

```
{d, h, bcg, age} = 
 Transpose@
  Rest@Import["http://www.rni.helsinki.fi/~kja/epid12/BCG.dat", 
    "Data"];
logitmodel = 
 GeneralizedLinearModelFit[Transpose@{bcg, d/h}, BCG, BCG, 
  ExponentialFamily -> "Binomial", LinkFunction -> Automatic, 
  Weights -> d + h]
logitmodel["ParameterTable"]
```

The results are estimates that are almost the same but differ in a few decimals. For example, the `R` estimate and standard error for BCG are -0.74152 and 0.12744 respectively. The corresponding *Mathematica* results are -0.742492 and 0.127755. Am I making a subtle mistake somewhere or is this the result of some numerical approximation?

Comment: I get {-0.7453603285, 0.1271282958} (Win7-64). Probably a numerical accuracy issue, but does it matter? The size of the differences is much smaller than the error in the estimates themselves.

Comment: With precision and accuracy set to 200 I get {-0.74536032846461989040..., 0.12712830428988635844565...}

Comment: @Sjoerd That's a valid point. However, subtle mistakes can occur in statistical analysis, so whenever a difference--no matter how small--cannot *definitively* be assigned to numerical imprecision, it ought to be tracked down. Kudos to Mr Alpha for being careful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To match what you're doing in `R`, you need to use `d/(d+h)` for the fractions rather than `d/h`:

```
logitmodel = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[Transpose@{bcg, d/(d + h)}, BCG, BCG, 
  ExponentialFamily -> "Binomial", LinkFunction -> Automatic, Weights -> d + h];
logitmodel["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

The clues that led to this realization were that the deviances, log likelihoods, and AICs could not be made to match, even after trying to make `glm.fit` more precise in `R` (and starting the optimization at the *Mathematica* values for the parameters): this indicated there really was something different between the two calculations.  Once it became apparent--upon inspecting the data--that `h` was huge compared to `d`, the source of the difference was evident.

Comment: Thank you. It was one of those mistakes that seems obvious in hindsight.